# If I want to motivate a reopen vote, is it ok to edit the question?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

Often when I vote to reopen a question, I feel that it would be good to motivate why it should be reopened. When it's closed as a duplicate that's fairly standard to add something like:

> EDIT: This is not a duplicate of Q because that question is about X, but this question is about Y, and none of the answers to Q answers my question.

Is this something I can do for other close reasons too?

If it matters, I'm primarily asking for questions where I'm not the OP.

Comment: If it's unclear it's hard to clarify it without the OPs understanding of what it's supposed to be. If it's too broad you can't narrow it without changing the OPs intent etc. What would you write therefore?

Comment: I don't think that saying *the question is not a duplicate* and *none of the answers to Q answers the question*  will convince the person who closed the question to reopen it. I usually close questions and the OP add such edit after few minutes without even taking the time to read the duplicates so I comment to add the solution and explain how it's a duplicate. I think the OP need to edit the question to really show that it's not a duplicate, not to say it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Do you have an example where that would be useful? I have thought about the common close reasons (unclear, typo, 'why not working', too broad) and I don't see why a text like that would be more useful than an overall edit of the question which makes the close reason obsolete. The latter also avoids "meta" noise in the question.

Comment: @Tom An example when I find it useful is when questions gets closed because "primarily opinion-based". It's common with questions which indeed HAS opinion-based answer, but also has completely valid objective answers.

Comment: Then edit the question to be less opinion-focused and more fact-based, to attract more answers like existing objective one? The close reason exists because such questions attract mostly opinion-based answers, not because there are only opinion-based answers possible.

Comment: @tom that's changing the OP's intent. They should do that themselves, other people shouldn't intervene.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's another issue as well, correct, I just was focused on the question: when will such block ever be better than an actual edit/fix of the question.

Comment: @klutt  A question is either asking for opinions or it's asking for something that is objectively verifiable.  While you can answer an objectively verifiable question with an opinion, that's just a wrong answer, if the question is in fact objectively answerable.  A question cannot have both opinion based and objective correct answers.  That doesn't even make sense.  What kind of question are  you thinking is like this?  Note that a question asking for opinions can contain *facts*, but it can't *objectively answer the question correctly*, if it is in fact opinion based.

Comment: @klutt For example, if someone asks, "What's your favorite color?" it doesn't matter how many [correct] facts you spout off about pink and all of the cool unique aspects of it, the question is still asking for opinions, and an answer full of facts about why you link Pink isn't an objectively correct answer, and *no answer can ever be objectively correct*, which is what makes the question opinion based.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. For instance the Q *"Is there any reason to write `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p))` instead of `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))`?"* an objective answer is *"Yes, it avoids duplication"* while a subjective is *"Yes, it looks better"*

Comment: @klutt That's a question asking for opinions, in which the answers are all opinions, and you're simply considering the "correct" answer the opinion you like more, which is exactly why we don't want questions asking for opinions.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. That's meta-information, and should just be posted as a comment.

You can edit a post to make the question more clear, and for duplicates, that might include adding why other questions don't answer it. But don't just add a *wrong close reason because* edit because that is not relevant to the question.

If you post a comment, that can also get flagged as no longer needed when the question is re-opened. For an edit, you would need to rollback, which can be cumbersome if there are subsequent edits that shouldn't get rolled back.

Comment: What exactly "That's meta-information, and should just be posted as a comment."? I see "This is not a duplicate of Q because that question is about X, but this question is about Y" as perfectly valid edit... and nowhere in the question OP seem to suggest that they want to add "This is not unclear question" type of edit... Really confusing how first line ("Nope") aligns  with the second "You can edit a post to make the question more clear..." (Maybe there is more context to the answer that is no longer in the question?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As I said, if it makes the question more clear, it's fine. Edits should be aimed at improving the question, not explaining votes. If you edit only to explain why a question is on-topic/should be reopened but it doesn't make the question more clear, that's not OK (and I often see this, especially with unexperienced OPs editing their own post). If it improves the question, and is relevant even after the votes are no longer relevant, then it's OK. The question is about possibly opinion-based questions, and I think it's hard to edit that one properly without changing the intent.